# How to create Timer on RxSwift to call the method every 10 seconds?

Tags: swift, timer, rx-swift

I want to create a Timer with RxSwift to call my method every 10 seconds, but l don't know how to make it the best way.

If you have any ideas, please, share!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for any extra libraries. The operator already exists in RxSwift.

```
Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(10), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
        myMethod()
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this pod [RxTimer](https://github.com/bmoliveira/RxTimer)

```
NSTimer.rx.timer(10)
  .subscribeNext { _ in
   print("timer triggered")
 }
 .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```